# htaccess how to rewrite any url ending with /feed/ to specific page?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rss

How can i implement wordpress like url rewrite logic , 
if some one adds `/feed/` at the end of any url then it should forward all get parameters to specific page .,

i tried doing something like this

```
RewriteRule ^feed/?$ rss.php [L]

RewriteRule ^feed/?$ rss.php [QSA,L]
```

and tried catching data like

**rss.php**

```
<?php
print_r($_GET);
?>
```

but it keep refreshing the current page where the link is placed.

e.g.
this

```
domain.com/browse/flowers/feed/
```

go to

```
domain.com/rss.php?category=flowers&feed=on
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reference: mod\_rewrite, URL rewriting and "pretty links" explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained)

Comment: @anubhava there are multiple GET parameters and 3-4 and 2 of them are optional. so i gotta catch everything which comes before ending /feed/

Comment: Then below answer should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

something like this should do it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^?/browse/(.*)/feed/?$ rss.php?category=$1$feed=on [L,NC,QSA]
```